# Swift call Function when ViewController is visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a small problem I sadly couldn't solve. I have a few ViewControllers. I need to call a function when going back from a ViewController to the previous ViewController (which does not reload, so viewDidLoad / Appear is not called).

Mustn't there be anything like viewDidLoad, but gets called every time the ViewController is visible?

This is how I open the ViewControllers:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "levels_vc") as! LevelsViewController
        present(vc, animated: true)
```

This is the way I try to get the event, but it only gets called the first time (when the ViewController loads the first time), but not when I open a new ViewController from this one and close the new one.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("VC appeared!")
    }
```

Comment: How are you "going back from a ViewController to the previous ViewController"?

Comment: Have you tried an unwind segue?

Comment: I did not use a seque. I'll add the way I open and close ViewControllers in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` for that purpose!.

**`viewWillAppear()`** is called every time the view will appear on the screen.
This can be useful for views that need to be updated every time they’re scrolled to. For example, the Now Playing section in a music app or any view that is updated when it is scrolled to.

**`viewDidAppear`** is called when the view has appeared on the users screen.
This is a good place to “lazy-load” any other elements onto your screen. If your user interface is very complicated, you don’t want to stall or cause a delay in the previous mentioned methods.
It’s better to load something onto the screen and then call some methods to update the views for some large applications.

This is also a create place to start any animations.

Comment: viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are both not called when I return to the ViewController, only when the ViewController loads the first time.

Comment: You are opening a vc through `storyboard.instatntiateViewController` which means everytime your `viewDidload`will also be called. Can you share the whole code?

Comment: And also, are you using any print statments or functions in `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` to confirm that they are not being called?

Comment: Yes, I'll share the code. I use print statements to confirm that they are not called.

Comment: By looking at this piece of code , Error can't be traced. You need to share the code of both the view Controllers in which you are navigating.

Answer (score 0):

That would be `ViewDidAppear()` [ViewDidAppear() - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear)

Comment: No, this is not called when I return to my ViewController.